# Why xmax system column in postgres table is not zero for non-deleted row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table:

```
       Table "public.product"
 Column |  Type   |                      Modifiers
--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('product_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "product_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "stock" CONSTRAINT "stock_product_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(id)
```

This table has 2 records :-

```
postgres=# select xmin, xmax, cmin, cmax, * from product;
  xmin   |  xmax   | cmin | cmax | id |  name
---------+---------+------+------+----+---------
 3126848 | 3126856 |    0 |    0 |  1 | Parle-G
 3126849 | 3126858 |    0 |    0 |  2 | Pepsi
(2 rows)
```

I have following questions related to xmax and cmin columns:-

1. As per postgres docs, xmax stores the id of the transaction, which deleted this row. But since my row is not yet deleted, then why does it contain non-zero value.
2. Postgres docs says that cmin contains the sequence number of statement in the transaction, which has created this row. As per SQL standard, every statement is a transaction on its own, so in that way, it must contains non-zero number for cmin column.

Please Correct me, where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first, since that is simple:

`cmin` starts counting at zero, so a `cmin` of zero means that this was the first statement in the transaction. If all your transactions consist of a single statement, you can expect `cmin` to be zero throughout.

About the meaning of `xmax`:

Apart from storing the number of the transaction that deleted the row, this system column is also used to store *row locks*. These are stored on the row itself rather than in shared memory to avoid overflows of the lock table.

Row locks are stored in two different ways:

- If only a single transaction holds a lock on a row, the transaction number is stored in `xmax`.
- If more than one transaction has a (shared) lock on a row, a *multixact* structure is created, and its number is stored in `xmax`.

There is no conflict between the different uses of `xmax`, because the database has additional information:

- Additional flags in the table row (that are not visible as system columns) disambiguate the meaning of `xmax`.
- The *commit log* stores if a transaction has committed or not. Only rows deleted by a committed transaction are really deleted.

To sum it up, if you see a non-zero value in `xmax`, that can mean four things:

- The row has been deleted or updated, and your query is running with a *snapshot* older than the modifying transaction.
- The row has been deleted or updated by a transaction that was rolled back.
- The row is locked or has been locked at some point in the past, and you see the transaction ID of the locking transaction.
- Like above, but you see a *multixact* value. You can use the function `pg_get_multixact_members` to see which transactions belong to it.

You might be interested in reading [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/whats-in-an-xmax/) where I explore this question in more detail.